# C#: How to find references to equals operator for a particular class in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I would like to override `.Equals` and the `==` operator for a class. I need to check whether there are any equality comparisons in use anywhere for that class at the moment. How would I do this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible as the equality comparison can be used indirectly (SortedList), or by derived types, or by methods calling your class by an implemented interface

Comment: Regrettably, that is an excellent point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In both cases, I would add the overload/override, and then use "Find Usages" (in Resharper), or "View Call Hierarchy" (Visual Studio native). If anything shows up, it will be a change.

Another approach (if neither is available) is to (**just while doing this**) add `[Obsolete]` to the override/overload methods you add - then any code that starts using them (i.e. has a change to behaviour) will show up as a warning.

Caveat: if the `override` (Equals) is part of an inheritance chain that *already* overrides `Equals`, note that code referencing the base-class will not appear in any of the above. This includes code using `object`.

Comment: @Frederik well, it is pretty unlikely that the existing code is using methods marked as deprecated, but point taken.

Comment: 'View Call Hierarchy' works fine for overloaded `.Equals`, but I can't use that option for `==`. When I try to, I get 'Cursor must be on a member name'.

Comment: 'View Call Hierarchy' on `.Equals` doesn't find my call to `==` although it does find my call to `.Equals`. I thought I'd check.

Comment: +1 for view call hierarchy, works a treat on ToString.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this by using Resharper.
Resharper has a 'find usages' function which is quite powerfull.

You could override the Equals method in the class, right click on it, and select find usages advanced if you have R# installed.

Then, you'll get a list of places where that method is used.