# How to skip overrides of a method when looking for all references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I would like to determine the impact that a code change within on override of Equals() in my class would have on the code.

```
  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
     // My code to be changed
     return true;
  }
```

When I do Shift-F12 to find all references, Visual Studio returns 126,703 places where I am calling object.Equals().

Is there a way to skip overrides of Equals() method when looking for references?

Comment: I see a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399284/c-how-to-find-references-to-equals-operator-for-a-particular-class-in-visual-s

Comment: I like Mark's [Obsolete] trick.

Comment: However, "error CS0809: Warning as Error: Obsolete member 'Foo.ToString()' overrides non-obsolete member 'object.ToString()'". And if "#pragma warning disable 809" then the [Obsolete] attribute is ignored. :-P

Comment: View call hierarchy does the trick, at least in the ToString case I was grappling with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `Equals` method is defined at an `object` level, an object of your class could easily be passed to a method that calls `Equals` knowing nothing more than that it is an `object`.

For example, if you ever add your object to a HashSet, or if you call `.Distinct()` on a collection that includes your object, then you will be indirectly invoking `Equals`.

The only way to find all the places that overriding `Equals` will affect is to find all the places that your class is being used and see what is done with it.

Comment: This explains it perfectly... but boy am I disappointed.  I've got a lot of code to comb through now.